# What is the file descriptor that the terminal uses to talk to an interactive program?

Tags: perl, unix, file-io, io

```
echo "abc" | less
```

less receives the 4 bytes "a", "b", "c", "\x0A" over STDIN, and displays "abc" to the user in its own special way (with the alternate screen mode, etc.).

Then user types "n" at the keyboard, less responds by writing "Pattern not found  (press RETURN)" in reverse color at the bottom-left of the terminal. We also see it print a series of tilde's along the left.

Clearly less had to have received input of the "n" character in order to know to attempt to search what was in its search buffer.

Where did it get "n" through? I typed it into the terminal, but is the terminal attached to less's STDIN? If so, wouldn't less just have stuck the "n" into the display buffer? Well, it'd be able to tell, but not if I ran `echo "abc" | tail -f` for example.

How can I mess around with this file descriptor? I am building a perl program to convert mouse escape codes to key codes so I can make a special pipeline or wrapped command/program that works like a pager but can be mouse-interactive. But I can't figure out how to get in there if less's STDIN is the input file rather than the terminal itself. I really hope it's possible for me to pipe the interactive terminal output through my mapper program.

I also know that it's possible to check if a program's STDIN is a terminal or not, but that doesn't help me to find out

1. whether a terminal is connected at all, or
2. how to redirect/pipe/munge that terminal file input that may not be STDIN

**Update**: Okay I did some digging, it looks like I've been searching for the magical `/dev/tty`. Hopefully someone can show me how to mess around with it.

**Update**: Refined question: Do I essentially need to build and run a `pty` on the specific instances of pagers that I need to translate their events for? Sounds like it will be a pain as I'll need to have all of this process management and stuff. `IO:Pty:Easy` looks promising though.

Comment: How to mess around with it? It is a special file, but it does act like a file: you open it and can read from and write to it. There is some funky stuff you may have to do with `termios` if you want the raw data, though.

Comment: You may want to look at the modules IO:Tty and IO::Pty on CPAN

Comment: @icktoofay Are you saying my program can `open` `/dev/tty`, and just write back the translated stuff into it, and that would be it? Seems like a pty (where I tell it to spawn `less` on my pty) makes more sense. Otherwise I'm not seeing how my program would be able to know that `/dev/tty` is the right `tty`. If I've got two interactive terminals open, there's more than one `tty`...

Comment: @StevenLu: No, I'm saying that `less` is simply opening `/dev/tty` and treating it like a plain file. Before your edit, I thought you were simply trying to write a program like `less`, not be a proxy around `less`.

Comment: I was hoping I'd be able to just use it on STDIN. I guess if I can stuff the file input to less as a file in an argument, maybe with `<()` then the STDIN could be the terminal, in which case I can use a pipe. Then wrap that in a script.

Answer (score 0):

if you do

```
$ lsof -p <pid-of-less>
```

you will see at the bottom something like

```
less    30875 user    3r   CHR    5,0      0t0    1037 /dev/tty
```

which shows you how `less` has open the controlling terminal `/dev/tty` to read commands.